# AVCaptureDevice is always null on simulator

Tags: ios, record, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I am trying to capture live microphone audio data.

I took the following from the apple example for `AVCaptureSession`.

```
AVCaptureSession *captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

AVCaptureDevice *audioCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioCaptureDevice error:&error];

if (audioInput) {
    [captureSession addInput:audioInput];
}
else {
    // Handle the failure.
    NSLog(@"ERROR");
}
```

`audioCaptureDevice` and `audioInput` are both null.

Comment: I have been experiencing the same after upgrading it to iOS 10.3. The UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage always returning null. I even try to implement "AVCaptureDevice.RequestAccessForMediaTypeAsync(AVMediaType.Video)" and "Adding NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in info.plist" but still no luck

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it should be. Because simulator doesn't have any microphone. You should always test any audio, video, rendering related task on a real device.

Take a look about [Limitations of Testing in iOS Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH4-SW1)

> Hardware Limitations While most of the functionality of iOS devices
> can be simulated in iOS Simulator, there are some hardware features
> that must be tested directly on a device. The hardware features that
> cannot be simulated are:
>
> Accelerometer
>
> Gyroscope
>
> Camera
>
> Proximity
>
> Sensor Microphone Input

Comment: Seems it can be rather tedious to check for specific results or verify it actually works. But if I have no other choice then I suppose it is what I got.

Comment: If you record audio on simulator using AVAudioRecorder, it works just fine! So the simulator does have access to the microphone. There must be different reason.

Answer (score 3):

The simulator cannot take the Mac microphone as a source. You need to use a real device to test that.

Answer (score 3):

Simulator is not having mic and camera. So Check like and proceed

```
if let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.audio) {
  // allocate AVCaptureDevice
}
```